# Terraform: how to build a new object/map from two other maps?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**Objective:**

Create a new object/map from two other maps based on one of its matching attributes (same value). The ultimate goal is to deploy azurerm_network_watcher_flow_log resources for multiple spoke/workload NSGs based on the actual location of their respective Network Watchers (e.g.: there are 8 spokes/workloads NSGs, but only two NetworkWatchers (one in westeurope and another in eastus2).

**Explanation:**

All of my code iterates (via for_each) over an object variable that contains most of the required data to deploy multiple resources on Azure, `var.spokes`. Here its output:

```
    + customerA = {
        + environment = "D"
        + location    = "westeurope"
        + name        = "customerA"
    }
    + customerB = {
        + environment = "D"
        + location    = "westeurope"
        + name        = "customerB"
    }
    + customerC = {
        + environment = "D"
        + location    = "eastus2"
        + name        = "customerC"
    }
```

Now, I need to match the `var.spokes` object/map with the output of another resource, `data.azurerm_network_watcher.nw`, which is this:

```
    + eastus2    = {
        + location            = "eastus2"
        + name                = "NetworkWatcher_eastus2"
        + resource_group_name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
        + tags                = {}
        + timeouts            = null
    }
    + westeurope = {
        + location            = "westeurope"
        + name                = "NetworkWatcher_westeurope"
        + resource_group_name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
        + tags                = {}
        + timeouts            = null
    }
```

**Premise(s)/restriction(s):**

- the final object/map must maintain the keys of `var.spokes` (customerA, customerB, etc.) as its primary key
- the final object/map must match the `location` attribute, which is the only common value in both source maps (`var.spokes` and `data.azurerm_network_watcher.nw`)

**Expected output:**

This is the desired output:

```
    + customerA = {
        + environment                 = "D"
        + location                    = "westeurope"
        + name                        = "customerA"
        + watcher_name                = "NetworkWatcher_westeurope"
        + watcher_resource_group_name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
    }
    + customerB = {
        + environment                 = "D"
        + location                    = "westeurope"
        + name                        = "customerB"
        + watcher_name                = "NetworkWatcher_westeurope"
        + watcher_resource_group_name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
    }
    + customerC = {
        + environment                 = "D"
        + location                    = "eastus2"
        + name                        = "customerC"
        + watcher_name                = "NetworkWatcher_eastus2"
        + watcher_resource_group_name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
    }
```

---

Silly things I've tried:

This:

```
    locals {
      spoke_nwatchers = {
        for k, v in var.spokes : k => {
          for i, n in values(data.azurerm_network_watcher.nw)[*] : i => {
            watcher_id                  = n.id,
            watcher_name                = n.name,
            watcher_resource_group_name = n.resource_group_name,
            watcher_location            = n.location
            environment                 = v.environment
          } if v.location == n.location
        }
      }
    }

    output "spoke_nwatchers" {
      value = local.spoke_nwatchers
    }
```

But it leads to weird results (an additional key attribute containing either 0 or 1).

And this, which is the closest I managed to get from the desired result:

```
locals {
  spoke_nwatchers = {
    for k, v in var.spokes : k => [
      for i, n in data.azurerm_network_watcher.nw : {
        watcher_id                  = n.id,
        watcher_name                = n.name,
        watcher_resource_group_name = n.resource_group_name,
        watcher_location            = n.location,
        environment                 = v.environment
      } if v.location == n.location
    ]
  }
}
```

But it gives me a tupple ("[]"), instead of a map ("{}"), containing the attributes in a single element.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you should do to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To have minimal changes to your code, just add `[0]` to your code:

```
locals {
  spoke_nwatchers = {
    for k, v in var.spokes : k => [
      for i, n in data.azurerm_network_watcher.nw : {
        watcher_id                  = n.id,
        watcher_name                = n.name,
        watcher_resource_group_name = n.resource_group_name,
        watcher_location            = n.location,
        environment                 = v.environment
      } if v.location == n.location
    ][0] #<--- HERE get the first element from the list
  }
}
```